# How to add a promise in the redux and execute according to Data

Tags: javascript, react-native, function, asynchronous, redux

I have a function that i am calling on a button click

```
const onButtonPress = () >{
   storeDataInDB()
}

const storeDataInDB= () =>{
// Call multiple functions inside here and take a 1 minute to process
// Some api requests in this function also
}
```

So As i am clicking on the button multiple so it executes my function parallel. So want to create a redux array to store it. So if user click on the button 100 times. So it will store 100 process in the redux and execute 1 by 1 and remove it from redux as it will be done. And if i want to remove 88 index process. So i can remove it from the redux. So i am not able to get how can i store a function in this manner. Let me know if anyone can help me in this logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
const storeDataInDB = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      // Do Call multiple functions and Api requests
      resolve(data) // return value when Promise Success
      reject(err) // return error value when Promise failed
}
```

The above code is to create a Promise and a Promise always have two conditions

- resolve (Success)
- reject (Fail)

To get values from a Promise, use `.then` and `.catch` method like following

```
const onButtonPress = () =>{
 storeDataInDB.then((data) =>{
   // return data on Promise Fulfilled
 }).catch((err) => {
   // return error on Promise failed 
 }
}
```

Comment: hi @Muhammad Ahab  how can i cancel any index request. And remove from redux? Will i store it in the object in redux. As it it start to execute it will work continually. So i want to go to another screen and i want to cancel it. Let me know if you will get my point.